# how to get Dc from directx3d?

Tags: directx, gdi

I need to get Device Context (DC ) from directx3d. Here some code snap.
1.CREATE DEVICE:

```
    int windowWidth = 640;
        int  windowHeight = 480;
        IDirect3D9* direct3D9 = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    if(direct3D9 == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    D3DDISPLAYMODE *d3ddisplayMode =(D3DDISPLAYMODE *)calloc(1,sizeof(D3DDISPLAYMODE));
    hr = direct3D9->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,d3ddisplayMode);
    if(hr != D3D_OK)
    {
                 free(d3ddisplayMode);
         direct3D9->Release();
         return FALSE;
    }
     D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS *d3dpresentParam                                             =(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS*)calloc(1,sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));
 d3dpresentParam->Windowed = TRUE;
 d3dpresentParam->hDeviceWindow = NULL;
 d3dpresentParam->SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
 d3dpresentParam->BackBufferFormat = d3ddisplayMode->Format;
 d3dpresentParam->BackBufferWidth = windowWidth;
 d3dpresentParam->BackBufferHeight = windowHeight;
 d3dpresentParam->BackBufferCount = 1;
 free(d3ddisplayMode);
 hr = direct3D9->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,NULL,D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,d3dpresentParam,&direct3D9Device);
```

2.CRETAE TEXTURE:

```
hr = D3DXCreateTexture(direct3D9Device,bmpWidth,bmpHeight,1,0,D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_MANAGED,&pTexture);
```

3.DISPLAY IMAGE:

```
 float left = 0,top =0,width =640,height=480;
 direct3D9Device->BeginScene();
    D3DXMATRIX mat;
D3DXVECTOR3 pos;

pos.x = (bmpWidth * left) / width;
pos.y = (bmpHeight * top) / height;
pos.z = 0;
d3dxSprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
D3DXVECTOR2 scaling((width/bmpWidth),(height/bmpHeight));
if(pTexture == direct3DTextureRemote )
{
    D3DXVECTOR2 spriteCentre((width/2),(height/2));

    D3DXMatrixTransformation2D(&mat,NULL,0.0,&scaling,&spriteCentre,NULL,NULL);
}
else
{
    D3DXMatrixTransformation2D(&mat,NULL,0.0,&scaling,NULL,NULL,NULL);
}
d3dxSprite->SetTransform(&mat);
d3dxSprite->Draw(pTexture,NULL,NULL,&pos,0xFFFFFFFF);
d3dxSprite->End();
direct3D9Device->EndScene();
direct3D9Device->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

Now Working probely. I can get dc from window like HDC hdc = ::GetDC(hwnd) but in my case if there is no window(i.e. windowless) then how can i get DC from directx. please give some piece of code get DC from directx device.

Comment: You supplied a `HWND` to `CreateDevice`, why not use that?

Comment: In above sample i supplied hwnd to createDevice.But now i need to draw the image in windowless part.so only i am asking how to get Dc from directx.

Comment: @user3336737 How you suppose *"to draw the image in windowless part"*? What is that part? What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Supplying `NULL` as the window handle to `Present()` just means it will use the `HWND` from the `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS`. You perhaps have to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Drop: I am developing a NPAPI windowless plugin for drawing.So i don't need to create a window. So i supplied NULL in createDevice.My question is "can we get Dc from directx device?" . If there is possible to get Dc then I will draw the image from NPP_HandleEvent by using DC.

Comment: @RogerRowland: Hi i supplied NULL for both D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS and CreateDevice.

Comment: Well, in the code you showed above, you didn't supply `NULL`.

Comment: Now i edited as NULL in both  D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS and CreateDevice.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`GetDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `null` as argument:

```
HDC hdc = ::GetDC(0);
```

Quote from MSDN:

```
    Parameters

    hWnd [in]

    A handle to the window whose DC is to be retrieved. 
    If this value is NULL, GetDC retrieves the DC for the entire screen.
```

**Edit:**

As we know now that you are using NPAPI, here is a possible solution:

Call NPAPI function [`NPN_GetValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/NPN_GetValue) with `NPNVnetscapeWindow` parameter. Returned `HWND` is a handle to plug-in drawing surface. Use it when create DirectX device and to retrieve `HDC`.

Alternatively, you could try to retrieve the back buffer (`IDirect3DSurface9`) via [`IDirect3DDevice9::GetRenderTarget()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method and then retrieve its `HDC` via [`IDirect3DSurface9::GetDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.In my case, I don't need Dc for the entire screen.Please help me if u know how do i get Dc from directx.

Comment: IDirect3DSurface9* render_target;
IDirect3DSurface9* sysmem_offscreen_surf;
direct3D9Device->CreateRenderTarget(backDcWidth, backDcHeight, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE, 0, TRUE, &render_target, NULL);

 
  direct3D9Device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(backDcWidth, backDcHeight, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &sysmem_offscreen_surf, NULL);
  //copy data from video mem to sysmem:
  direct3D9Device->GetRenderTargetData(render_target, sysmem_offscreen_surf);
  
  sysmem_offscreen_surf->GetDC(&hdc);

Comment: I get only black screen... I checked out getting Dc is NULL or not... Getting Dc is Not NULL... Then how i get black screen only instead of image